# Creating Datasource Dynamically in SpringBoot OpenJPA Application (Implementing Multitenancy with OpenJPA)

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, datasource, multi-tenant, openjpa

I am creating a Springboot application with OpenJPA.

My requirement is that I need to connect to multiple datasources dynamically and the datasource credentials are obtained at runtime by calling some rest-endpoints.

Here is the controller class:

```
@RestController
public class StationController {

@Autowired
BasicDataSource dataSource;
```

I have a service which returns me the jdbc_url depending on the customer name:

```
public String getDSInfo(String customername){
    // code to get the datasource info (JDBC URL)
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a way in which I can create datasources at runtime by getting datasource credentials by calling some other service (which takes the customer id and returns the customer specific datasource) ?
2. Since my application is a web based application, many customers will be accessing it at the same time, so how to create and handle so many different datasources?

NOTE:

1. The code will get information about the customer specific data source only by firing some service at the runtime, so I cannot hardcode the datasource credentials in the XML configuration file.
2. I found some implementations with Hibernate but i am using Springboot with OpenJPA. So need OpenJPA specific help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a multi-tenancy solution.

Datasources are easy to create programmatically, just use a DataSourceBuilder with your connection details pulled in from a central source (e.g. a central config database or Spring Config Server).

Then you'll need to look at a multi-tenancy framework to tie the datasources back to clients.

See here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBSHiUTHjWA

and here

https://dzone.com/articles/multi-tenancy-using-jpa-spring-and-hibernate-part

The video is a long watch but a good one. Basically you have a map of customer data sources (from memory) that allow an entityManager to pick up a datasource from the map by using a thread scoped custom spring scope of "customer" which is set when a user for a particular customer somehow logs into your app.

Comment: Let me try. Does this solution also works in case of multiple customers accessing the application at the same time ?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. A particular custom could get to the app by passing a customer specific code on the URL.  When they log in this gets set on a thread local and then from then on when they do any data access via your custom entitymanager, the entitymanager grabs the customer's datasource from the map. The magic is the use of a customer custom scope. This is all explained in the last 10-15 minute of the video.

Comment: Thanks for the links, are these also applicable for spring OpenJPA application as well ?

Comment: The links shared are applicable for Hibernate , not for OpenJPA

Comment: I don't think the approach shown in the video is Hibernate specific, after all, all that it's doing is picking a datasource to use at run time based on a custom scope. We're planning to use exactly that approach with Eclipselink at work.